# Query function with variable in the Col1=

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

Here' the formula:
`=query({{$P$3:$P$34;$R$3:$R$34;$T$3:$T$34;$V$3:$V$34;$X$3:$X$34;$Z$3:$Z$34;$AB$3:$AB$34;$AD$3:$AD$34},{$Q$3:$Q$34;$S$3:$S$34;$U$3:$U$34;$W$3:$W$34;$Y$3:$Y$34;$AA$3:$AA$34;$AC$3:$AC$34;$AE$3:$AE$34}}, "select Sum(Col2) where Col1='Adonist'",0)`

I'm on the very edge of my understanding on this formula but, at the end of the formula where it says, where Col1''Adonist'",0)   where it says Adonist (Employee name) I want to put the employee name from cell P37 (Currently says Adonist). When employees come/go, I don't want to have to change the formula with the new name.  When I try to replace 'Adonist' with 'P37' or '"P37"' or any other variation, it just gives me an error. The value in P37 is pulled from a list of employees on another sheet. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `where Col1='Adonist'",0)` use `where Col1='"&P37&"'",0)`.

The above because the QUERY function second parameter is a TEXT value so to add a cell value as part of a condition, this cell value can be inserted by splitting the second parameter and concatenating the parts. In this case `&` used for the concatenation.